# I don't understand pointers in dynamic memory allocation

Tags: c

Memory dynamically allocated using malloc is done like this:

```
int *ptr=(int*)(malloc(sizeof(int)))
```

I don't understand why pointer is used before `malloc` in `(int*)` and why we have another pointer with `int *ptr`.

I am sorry to put up this basic question here and bother people here with this one. But I am not clear after googling this and need help.

Thank You.

Comment: *why pointer is used* This is called a cast. It is not necessary or recommended. You can omit it: `int *ptr=malloc(sizeof(int))`.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Thanks. I didn't know we could do that.

Comment: For further details on why the cast is unnecessary -- see [Do I cast the result of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `malloc` allocates space for an `int` using `sizeof(int)`.
2. malloc returns a pointer, which is converted to `int *` using `(int*)`.
3. Finally, it assigns that pointer to `ptr`, which could also be written as

   `int* ptr =`
4. Now `ptr` has the value from `malloc`.

There is no difference in

```
int *ptr=(int*)(malloc(sizeof(int)));
```

and

```
int* ptr=(int*)(malloc(sizeof(int)));
```

but in my opinion, the second one is clearer, because it has the same notation as the cast.

As the commenter said, it can be simplified to:

```
int* ptr=malloc(sizeof(int));
```

which, to me, is the clearest and simplest of all.  Hope this helps!

Comment: better use object in sizeof instead of type  `int *ptr=malloc(sizeof(*ptr));`

Comment: Second variant may confuse when `int* a, b`. `a` is a pointer, `b` is an `int`.

Comment: I Second the second. `int* a, b, c;` does NOT declare 3 pointers to `int`, it declares one pointer `a` and two `int`, `b` and `c`. `int *a, b, c;` makes that clear.

Answer (score 0):

The `(int *)` before the `malloc` call is a *cast* - it means "convert the return value of `malloc` to type `int *` before assignment".

With one exception, different pointer types cannot be directly assigned to each other - you cannot assign a `char *` value to an `int *` object or vice versa without an explicit cast.  Prior to the 1989 version of the C language definition (C89), `malloc`, `calloc`, and `realloc` all returned `char *`, so if you wanted to assign the result to a different pointer type, a cast was always necessary:

```
int *foo = (int *) malloc( N * sizeof *foo);
double *bar = (double *) calloc( N, sizeof *bar );
struct s *blurga = (struct s *) realloc( bletch, 2 * N * sizeof *blurga );
```

This, as you can imagine, was a pain in the ass.

To help solve this and several other problems, C89 introduced the `void` type, along with a special rule that allows you to assign `void *` values to other pointer types and vice versa without an explicit cast.  It also changed the `*alloc` functions to return `void *`, so those calls can now be written as

```
int *foo = malloc( N * sizeof *foo );
double *bar = calloc( N, sizeof *bar );
struct s *blurga = realloc( bletch, 2 * N * sizeof *blurga );
```

`void` is an empty type with no size and no values, so you can't dereference a `void *` or do pointer arithmetic on it, but you can use it as a "generic" pointer type to store pointer values without really caring about the type of the pointed-to object.

Note that C++ does *not* allow `void *` values to be assigned to other pointer types without a cast, so you'd still need the cast for `malloc` calls, but it you're writing C++ you shouldn't be using `malloc` anyway.

Answer (score 0):

`int * ptr`  declare a pointer variable.

`( int * )`  cast the result of malloc to the type of variable you declared

`malloc (sizeof (int))`  you get the memory you need

Answer (score -1):

a (int *) pointer is a variable that contains a location of memory where (int) is stored, so think about it as a regular variable

than you are calling for malloc - this function tries to get free memory, actually, malloc returns memory without any specification and its type (void *), so you can convert it into (int *), it will be (int *) malloc
and as you have variable int *ptr, you can write

```
int *ptr; // declaring our pointer like any other variable
ptr = (int *) malloc (sizeof (int)); // trying to get some memory
```

or

```
int * ptr = (int *) malloc (sizeof (int)); // same thing, but one string
```

Comment: your question seems not clear. but if I explain in very basic level,  think the integer pointer variable as same as another known variable type. For example, in int x =5; value 5 is assigned to variable called 'x'.  in the same way in  int * ptr = (int *) malloc (sizeof (int)); it assigns a memory space equals to size of an integer, to the pointer variable